# How to show progress with percentage in the form of color change on top of a image

Tags: android, progress-bar

I am very new to Android.

I want to have a horozontal progressbar like below image(**I have a rectangle horizontal bar image with 4 divider,in that image i need to show progress with red color**).For that i am adding setIndeterminateDrawable to progressBar and am getting the image in the background of progressbar.

In the same image i want to show progress like below with red color
Below is my code of xml layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/pb_test"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:max="100"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

And code of Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

 ProgressBar progressBar;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);
        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.pb_test);
        progressBar.setIndeterminateDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.pbimage));
        progressBar.setProgress(30);
        }
    }
```

How to show the progress of 30% with red color like above image.How to do this.
I am new to stackoverflow,so i am not able to upload any image.

Comment: where is image?

Comment: I am not able to upload image as i am new to stackoverflow :(

Comment: @SanjayKumar is there any way to upload image?

Comment: @Ravikumar You can upload the image to www.imgur.com and paste the link in the question.

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you look at [this](https://github.com/DreaminginCodeZH/MaterialProgressBar) library it has various examples also which do your thing

**EDIT**

see [this](https://github.com/RahulJanagouda/StatusStories) library for a progress bar for images as in whatsapp status, instagram and snapchat

Comment: Hi @Ali kaissi i have checked this library.my requirment is something different.i  have a horizontal bar image with 4 divider.In that image i need to show progress with red color

Comment: well you should specify that in your question + provide what you have done or at least something that tells what you want to do...

Comment: just now i have updated the question with image description.Whatever i have tried i have mentioned.I am not geeting how to show progress on a image.